# Hide iframe but somehow disengage it

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am creating a website which hosts 360 panaramic photography. I am creating basically a slideshow of 360's using an iframe with tiled thumbnails. When the user clicks on a tile it loads that 360 into the iframe through JS by changing the src value of the iframe.

My issue is bandwidth, If I use the method of loading the src value into the iframe then every time this occurs, it seems to reload the content - looking at my network tab in my browser this does seem to be the case, I can see the image files being reloaded for a second time if the user re-views a tile/iframe.

My other option would be to have multiple iframes and just hide or show them based on which tile was clicked. Maybe using 'display:none'?

However would this then create the issue of multiple 360 panoramic photos running at the same time and being taxing on the users computer/ graphics card? Or would display:none then disengage the iframe from creating work for the graphics card?

Is there anyway to tell whether the iframe has been disengaged when hidden and is no longer taxing the users computer?

And if it is, then is there a way around this somehow? Can an iframe be disengaged so that it isn't running so to speak but it can still be made visible to the user again without reloading the content again.

Thanks, I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved using two things: **Lazy Loading** and **Visibility**.

You can achieve the lazy loading either the native way

```
<iframe src="your-360-image" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

or using one of the libraries that does it for you, [Iframely](https://iframely.com/docs/lazy-load) and [lazyframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazyframe) are good ones.

You can set the all the iframes to start loading in the background when the user is near them, so by the time the user clicks the tile, it's already loaded.

Regarding that the browser reloads the images, that might be because you set `display` to `none`, or even remove the element completely from the DOM. You might just want to hide it by setting the `visibility` to `hidden`, this should not re-load it again.

Comment: Thanks very much, would using 'visibility:hidden' mean that the iframe would stop taxing the users computer. As you can imagine having several 360 images all loaded up and moving at the same time does create some lag on the graphics card.